# Which Schengen visa should one apply for when visiting a workshop?

Tags: visas, schengen, italy, hong-kong-citizens

My SO plans to attend an art workshop held in Italy spanning 6 months. The workshop takes 2 full weeks per month. We are not sure about which visa he should apply. The workshop is not held by an registered education institution, so I doubt whether they will accept if he applied for a study visa.

As a sidenote, he is a Hongkonger and he holds a HKSAR passport (but doesn't currently hold, though eligible for, a British National (Overseas) Passport, if this makes a difference).

Which visa should he apply for in this situation?

Comment: Have you already tried asking the organizers?

Comment: As I understand it, a British National (Overseas) would be covered by Annex II. Six times two weeks are 84 days. It may be possible to come without a visa. If your SO does not plan to go home each time, he or she is beyond the 90/180 rule and requires a D visa. Questions about that are more fitting on the Expats site.

Comment: @mts Their participants were mostly European so they aren't too familiar about this.

Comment: @o.m. For both BN(O) and HKSAR passport, we are eligible for a visa-free travel for 90 days every 180 days in Schengen area. During the breaks, he can "hop" to France and hop back in to Italy before workshop. But the point is, IDN whether this is legal to do so, and whether or not applying the visa is the way to go

Comment: Mind the 90/180 rule is for the whole Schengen zone, so hopping to France would be of no use unless he has a residence permit or similar there. UK would do though.

Comment: @mts oh! I didn't realise this. Thanks! So a no go for this route...

Comment: "doesn't currently hold, though eligible for, a British National (Overseas) Passport", Ron, it is madness that your friend does not get a "BNOP". If they are eligible, they should stop everything and get one! Maybe this triup is a good spur to action.

Comment: @om Can you elaborate a bit more what a D visa is? We are kind of ignorant on the Italian visa types.

Comment: @Joe Blow the application fee is kinda steep. I have a BNO but he isn't too willing to pay the price...

Comment: @RonLau, Schengen D visa are *national* residence permits from any one Schengen state. Each Schengen state can establish slightly different criteria and procedures how they are granted. Having one of those allows travel in the *other* Schengen states as if one had a multi-entry Schengen C visa, which is normal tourist/business visa.

Comment: @o.m. There's also the question of if this activity is allowed as a "C" visitor, as well as the time considerations. But yeah, an Italian "D" visa seems best.

Comment: In fact, a D visa isn't a specific visa type at all, it's a generic name for all national visas. Hopefully someone can provide more details regarding Italy.

Comment: @o.m. A D visa is a visa, not a residence permit. And a C visa is not a tourism/business, it's short-stay visa can can cover many other purposes.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. I'll look into Italian national visa. Once again, thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common Schengen Type C visa (short-term visit) is intended for stays of up to 90 days in any 180 day period. The activity proposed lasts longer than that so is clearly not eligible for a C visa. That only leaves Type A (Airport Transit visa) and Type B (Transit visa), which clearly would not suit, and Type D (a national visa).

Queries regarding Type D (for longer-term) are generally a matter for [Expatriates](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) rather than Travel.

Comment: Type B visas were abolished several years ago.